# Discrete Math: Probability with subgraphs and coin flips.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices, in which each pair of vertices is connected by
an edge. For each each edge $e$ of $K_n$, we flip a fair and independent coin; if the coin comes
up heads, we color $e$ red, if it comes up tails, we color $e$ blue.
Assume that the vertex set of $K_n$ is ${1, 2, 3, . . . , n}$. Let $K'$ be the subgraph of $K_n$ induced
by the vertices 1, 2, . . . , k (i.e., an edge (i, j) of $K_n$ is in $K'$
if and only if both i and j are at
most k). Let A be the event
A = “all edges of $K'$ have the same color”
What is Pr(A)?

(a) $1/2^\binom{k}{2}$

(b) $2/2^\binom{k}{2}$

(c) $2^\binom{k}{2}/2^\binom{n}{2}$

(d) $2*2^\binom{k}{2}/2^\binom{k}{2}$

could anyone explain to me. I do not know why it is 2/2^(kC2). I thought it was a)

Answer (score 0):

$K'$ has $\binom {k}{2}$ edges.  Hence,
$$Pr(A) = Pr (\text {"all edges in } K' \text { are red"}) + Pr (\text {"all edges in } K' \text { are blue"}) = 2 \cdot (1/2)^{\binom {k}{2}}$$